# Hibernate Search ContainedIn on 1-way Relationship

Tags: hibernate-search

In hibernate search is there a way to use ContainedIn to update the index on the unrelated end of a 1-way relationship?

Say I have three classes A, B, C that are associated like this:

```
@Indexed
Class A {
    @IndexedEmbedded
    B classBObject
}

Class B {
    @IndexedEmbedded
    C classCObject
}

Class C {
    @ContainedIn
    B classBObject

    @Field
    int myInt
}
```

Is there a way, short of making the relationship bi-directional, to mark Class B as contained in Class A so that when I update myInt in Class C it will trigger an update in the index to update the embedded field in Class A's index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the relationship needs to be two-way for this.

N.B. there is no real drawback in Hibernate by adding the opposite side of the relation, other than having to add the property (or field).
So it might be interesting to also comment on why you'd want this.

Comment: Much appreciated. It wouldn't be practical; Class B doesn't really care that Class A exists and there are going to be a ton of Class A so management of the relationship back would be cumbersome.

Comment: Since Hibernate 5, if you instrument your classes you no longer need to keep both sides of a relation in synch (it's automatic, you can update either side). So the only drawback is setting up the metadata correctly.

Comment: Ended up doing that so the containedin works like a charm. Thanks for the help.